# Dynamically create a matrix of ImageViews in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I'm having an issue with creating a matrix of images in `RelativeLayout`. I manged to create only one row of it, the other rows are just not showing at all.

```
int index=1;
    for(int i=0;i<Globals.NUM_ROWS;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<Globals.NUM_COLS;j++)
        {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.obs_block);
            iv.setId(index);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            if(i!=0 && i%Globals.NUM_COLS==0){
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,index-Globals.NUM_COLS);
            }else{
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, index-1);
            }

            gameLayout.addView(iv, lp);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't build the `Relative.LayoutParams` correctly. See if this helps:

```
        int index = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Globals.NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Globals.NUM_COLS; j++) {
                ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
                img.setId(index);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                if (j == 0) {
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,
                            RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                } else {
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, index - 1);
                }
                if (i == 0) {
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,
                            RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                } else {
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, index - Globals.NUM_COLS);
                }
                img.setLayoutParams(rlp);
                rl.addView(img);
                index++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: the matrix of images is aligned towards the left hand side of screen can it be centered ? I need it very urgent  Thamks in Advance @Luksprog

Comment: @user990967 You can try using `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)`(or the `android:gravity="center"` property in the xml layout) on the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @Luksprog Both of them dint work ..Its very urgent can you please fina a solution I tried androd:gravity="center" but it dint work and rlp.setGravity() is not present

Comment: @user990967 The `RelativeLayout` does have a method `setGravity()` and it should work(maybe try without the `ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT` and `ALIGN_PARENT_TOP` rules for the first row). And you could also make the `RelativeLayout` containing the matrix have wrap_content for width/height and then centering it in another layout like `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Ih used the re.setGravity(Gravity.Center) but it dint work(I have already removed the ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT and ALIGN_PARENT_TOP) from the prvious code. I want to add the Matrix of Images Dynamically I will know the number of rows and cols in runtime

Comment: @user990967 You should ask a new question mentioning what layout you have and other details. What I said above should work for a simple layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526772/centering-the-matrix-of-imageviews-to-the-center-of-the-screen-dynamically  see dis Question i have just posted